# Nvidia compute visual profiler always shows press any key to continue

Tags: cuda, nvidia

When I run my .exe file using profiler, it shows Press any key to continue in the first run and times out. But, i am not asking for a key press in my program. Then why is it showing this?

```
Start program 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Hypermedia/Rice Coding Compression WritingtoBinFile/bin/win32/Debug/vectorAdd.exe ' run #3 ...
Press any key to continue .
```

Why the press key to continue?

Comment: This also happens if you run the program from the command line?

Comment: @pQB: no . then it just shows command prompt and closes. no need key press

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior in Nvidia sdk samples. Use the command line argument

```
--noprompt
```

to disable.

Comment: When do we use this command. at the time of compiling or at time of running. Moreover, how to put this command in vs 2008

Comment: The visual profiler has a field for arguments in the profile application dialog box.